# Generate database table from Umbraco content nodes

Tags: c#, sql, database, asp.net-core, umbraco

I'm currently working on a project to generate forms from the Umbraco (V.10) backend (I know that there is Umbraco Forms, but this is not an option).

I have a parent Node called "Formular" this generates the `<form>` tag. The parent can have various children like "Input Form Field", "Date Time Form Field" etc. These create an `<input>` field.

[Document types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61PbY.png)

What I want to do is to generate a database table from all child nodes of the "Formular" node. The database attribute names should be the node ID.
A child node has a radio list with types like "text", "textarea", "number" etc. to set the `<input type="">`. If the type is getting changed or a node is deleted, a new table should be generated with the new child nodes. It would be an option to update the table if a new node was added and to set the previous entries to null in this column.

[Example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkPzA.png)

I thought that I could create a custom section where all child nodes are shown with their datatype and a button that is activated if any changes were made in the nodes. If the button is getting clicked, it generates the new table (maybe the table name could be set in the section too).

If this helps somehow, I can send my form with ajax this is how it looks:

[Ajax POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/savMo.png)

I tried to create a table with the id and data types which I get from my ajax post, but I realized, that it is dumb to always check if the id and datatype are the same in the table and to create a new one if this is false. So I thought about creating the table directly from the Umbraco nodes.

My problem is, that I don't know how to generate the table if I don't have a model with attributes like "public int ...". And since there is no way to generate these attributes with a loop i have no idea how to create the table.

Any thoughts on this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide more details? For example, some code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been working on that for quite a long time, but I could figure out a better way than creating the database table from the content nodes.

I just generated a table "FormSubmission" that saves a nodeId each time the form has been submitted. Then I created a second table named "FormContext". This one is related to the ID of the submission, and each input field gets saved as one table entry in the "FormContext" table with the submission ID as foreign key.

[UML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz9fr.png)

This way I'm able to select all entries of a specific form and I can select all content a person has entered into the form.

Since I have all types an input field can have in the table, I don't have to update the table when the form changes or one form gets deleted.

I then created the tables like the umbraco documentation tells and just had to insert the data into the tables.
[Umbraco creating a custom database table](https://docs.umbraco.com/v/10.x-lts/umbraco-cms/extending/database)

I know this is not the most beautiful way but it works.